# My inputs wont let me move the cursor with the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a wierd one,

both inputs and text areas, cant move through the text with the left and right arrows?

there's lots of javascript/jquery on the page so it's likely a plugin is overriding, but thought i'd see if anyone's ever had a similar experience or got any pointers before i wade through mountains of code!

Comment: u should show your code and markup

Comment: But please don't post all of it your question; post a minimal test case. Also link to a live page and specify which browsers (including version numbers) you've tested and which exhibit the undesired behavior.

Comment: becuase it's an ajax web app, there's alot of code potentially influencing the page so would be too much to post.

was hoping someone might have some tips for the kind of thing i should be looking out for

ie it's probably javascript doing this right?
so i should investigate/detach my scripts one at a time?

Comment: just tested it and the same problem in all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the jquery dialog box I was using (fancybox) has a problem with inputs/cursors, not just in my instance.

I'm going to try using http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ instead and see if it works

Comment: Congratulations on finding the cause. Note that you can accept your own answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it)